# Bash: Find folder containing two files

Tags: bash, find

Hy,
I got a large directory-tree. I want to find out all directories which contain a file, which name ends with ".ext1" and a file which name ends with ".ext2".

How is this possible? I thought about using two finds, one for ".ext1" and one for ".ext2", but then I need to find the intersection, how can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a relatively simple solution that runs `find` only once, stores its output in a temporary file and then splits out and collates the results for the two extensions.

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
find . -name '*.ext1' -o -name '*.ext2' | sort >"$tmp"
comm -12 <(<tmp sed -n 's!/[^/]*\.ext1$!!p' | sort) \
         <(<tmp sed -n 's!/[^/]*\.ext2$!!p' | sort)
rm "$tmp"
```

Another method is to run `find` to iterate over the directories and uses an auxiliary program to check whether a pattern has matches. Note that the existence check works in this case, but you need something more complicated if your search pattern doesn't match itself  and is a possible file name.

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '{ set "$0"/*.ext1; [ -e "$1" ]; } &&
                            { set "$0"/*.ext2; [ -e "$1" ]; }' {} \;
```

Here's a zsh solution that operates like this last command:

```
echo **/*(/e\''set -- $REPLY/*.ext1(N[1]) $REPLY/*.ext2(N[1]); ((#==2))'\')
```

Here's another zsh solution that looks for `*.ext1` and selects only the directories that also have `*.ext2`:

```
echo ./**/*.ext1(e\''REPLY=${REPLY:h}; set -- $REPLY/*.ext2(N); ((#))'\')
```

Here's a partial Perl solution; due to the vicissitudes of Perl's globbing, it won't work if directory names contain spaces (there are ways to fix this, but I can't find one that's remotely elegant).

```
perl -l -MFile::Find -e \
  'find {no_chdir => 1,
         wanted => sub {<$_/*.ext1> and <$_/*.ext2> and print}}, "."'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the exact name of each file:

```
find start_dir -type d -exec test -e {}/file.ext1 -a -e {}/file.ext2 \; -print
```

The exceptionally ugly hack will work if all you know are the extensions:

```
find start_dir -type d -execdir bash -c 'shopt -s nullglob; eval '\''test -n "$(echo '{}'/*.ext1)" -a -n "$(echo '{}'/*.ext2)"'\''' \; -print
```

It could also be pretty slow if you have a lot of directories to search.

Comment: +1 for making me laugh when your self-proclaimed "hack" started to unravel :-) . Well played, sir.

Answer (score 1):

If run from the head of the directory tree, this seems to work

```
find $(find . -name "*.ext1" -printf %h\\n) -name "*.ext2" -printf %h\\n
```

Comment: +1 Good! But it can output more instances of a same directory if it contains two or more files that match the pattern, for example: a.ext1 b.ext1 c.ext2. `[...] | sort -u` may help.

Comment: It doesn't work if directory names include spaces.

Comment: @Dennis: Right! Again... :)

Comment: Building on this, I think I have a solution to the "names with spaces" problem. See https://superuser.com/a/1789735/73961

Answer (score 0):

There **must** be a better solution, but:

```
find -type d | while read i ; do [ `ls "$i" -1 | grep -oe '.ext1$\|.ext2$' | sort -u | wc -l` = 2 ] && echo $i ; done
```

Comment: You need the directory to search in there `find <directory> -type d ... `

Comment: I prefer that `find` works in the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the other answer using `find`, which as per comments doesn't work with spaces in paths, one could use `xargs` together with `find [...] -printf` to first find directories containing the first filename/extension, then use that list of directories to find the second filename/extension. For example, given some starting directory `dir` (broken up on multiple lines only for readability):

```
$ find dir -name "*.ext1" -exec printf '%q\n' {} \; | \
   xargs -I{} dirname {} | \
   xargs -I{} printf '%q\n' {}  | \
   xargs -I{} find {} -name '*.ext2' -printf '%h\n'
```

One caveat is that if a directory contains two (or more) files matching either extension, that directory will show up twice (or more); if this is a problem, just append  `... | sort -u` to the pipe.

Notes: the `xargs -I{} cmd {}` is just used to stick the command `cmd` where you want inside the `xargs` statement. The `find` command has a built-in `-printf` option that can quote the output string (as an alternative to null-terminated strings using `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...`). The `find` command's `-print '%h'` prints the `dirname` of the current argument.